# Manipulating a tab control

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a form with a bunch of tabs on it, but I don't want them to all be visible all the time.
I've tried

```
    For Each t In TabControl1.TabPages
        t.Hide()
    Next
    TabControl1.TabPages("DateRange").Show()
```

in order to hide them all on doc load and then .Show() for just the tabs that I want at that time, but that apparently doesn't work that way, as all the tabs are still visible.

Then I tried

```
Private tabs As TabControl.TabPageCollection

    For Each t In TabControl1.TabPages
        tabs.Add(t) ' Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '

        TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(t)
    Next
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabs("DateRange"))
```

but I get a tabs is not set to an instance of an object... And I get errors if I try to use

```
tabs = New TabControl.TabPageCollection
```

its frustrating that .Hide or .Visible don't do what they are supposed to.

Comment: seen
[this](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/windowsforms/t12906-how-hide-tabpage-tabcontrol.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path, except instead of

```
Private tabs As TabControl.TabPageCollection
```

use

```
Private tabs As New List(Of TabPage)
```

Comment: It looks like this will do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot continue around the loop removing as the index moves when an item is removed.

Setup your tabs and then remove them one by one either by index or name:

```
tabctrl.TabPages.RemoveAt(indx)

For x = 0 To tabctrl.TabPages.Count - 1
   If tabctrl.TabPages(x).Name.Equals(tabToRemove.Name) Then
      tabctrl.TabPages.RemoveAt(x)
      Exit For
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Close, but backwards. I want them all hidden and then only show the valid ones.

Comment: If you know which are the valid ones before removal, just remove the invalid ones by name you will have to use the for each loop for each tab.

Comment: If you want to remove them all then just keep calling tabctrl.TabPages.RemoveAt(0)

Comment: As your GUI state changes remove the "hidden" ones by name and then use either tabctrl.TabPages.Add or tabctrl.TabPages.Insert to "show"

Answer (score 1):

Moving a page that needs to be hidden into a List is the simple approach.  However, such a hidden page also needs to be disposed when the form closes.  It won't be automatic anymore since the TabControl cannot see the page.  And you can't ignore it, forgetting to dispose a control is a permanent leak.  Make it look like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private hiddenPages As New List(Of TabPage)

    Friend Sub SetTabState(ByVal page As TabPage, ByVal visible As Boolean)
        If visible Then
            If TabControl1.TabPages.Contains(page) Then Exit Sub
            hiddenPages.Remove(page)
            TabControl1.TabPages.Add(page)
        Else
            If Not TabControl1.TabPages.Contains(page) Then Exit Sub
            hiddenPages.Add(page)
            TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(page)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        For Each page As TabPage In hiddenPages
            page.Dispose()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'd like to learn more about this issue with the TabControl.  Do you have any links that discuss it?

Comment: @Jay - it simply isn't supported by the native Windows control.  What it can do is described in the SDK docs, start reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486050%28VS.85%29.aspx